# I need to split a seismological file so that I have multiple subfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Basically what I have is an ASCII file containing seismological information of various earthquake events. Each event (with its specific info) is separated from the following by a jumpline.

What I want is to split this huge file using python into a series of subfiles that contain approximately 700 events each with its own information, and these subfiles must be chronologically organized.

The original file look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see that between the first and second event is a jumpline and so every following events.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "empty line" is more clear than "jump line" ;-)

Comment: if all the events are on the same number of lines and are already in chronologic order in the input file you can use command like _split_ under linux/unix to cut your file in several

Comment: The problem is some events have more lines than others. But they are always separated by a empty line.

Comment: please, insert your data as text since it is a text, also show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you can do like that:

```
inputFile = "AllEvents.txt"               # give the path to the file that contain all the events
eventInfo = ""                            # create a string to hold event info
eventCounter = 0
fileId = 0

subFile= open("Events" + str(fileId) + ".txt","w+")          # create the sub file that you need

with open(inputFile) as fileContent:
    for line in fileContent:
        if not line.strip():              # strip white spaces to be sure is an empty line
            subFile.write(eventInfo + "\n")      # add event to the subFile
            eventInfo = ""                # reinit event info
            eventCounter += 1
            if eventCounter == 700:
                subFile.close()
                fileId += 1
                subFile = open("Events" + str(fileId) + ".txt","w+")
                eventCounter = 0
        else:
            eventInfo += line
subFile.close()
```

At the end you will have a list of files, each with 700 events: Events0.txt, Events1.txt, ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this. And how do I make each subfile to contain 700 events? The last one would probably have less but that doesn't matter

Comment: I updated the code, to write only 700 events/file. Please marks my answer as ok, if this helps you

Comment: It did work! But somehow the jumplines are lost, and I need them in the new subfiles.

Comment: Ok,I added a "\n" in the file.write() step

Comment: Perfect! You saved me today

Comment: Hi I hope you're alright!, I wonder if I can delete events with the statement 'RSN  3' on their first line