# I need to clean seismological events from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, data-cleaning

The question here is related to the same type of file I asked another question about, almost one month ago ([I need to split a seismological file so that I have multiple subfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159424/i-need-to-split-a-seismological-file-so-that-i-have-multiple-subfiles)).

My goal now is to delete events which in their first line contain the string 'RSN  3'. So far I have tried editing the aforementioned question's best answer code like this:

```py
with open(refcatname) as fileContent:
    for l in fileContent:
        check_rsn_3 = l[45:51]
        if check_rsn_3 == "RSN  3":
            line = l[:-1]
            check_event = line[1:15]
            print(check_event, check_rsn_3)
        if not check_rsn_3 == "RSN  3":
            # Strip white spaces to make sure is an empty line
            if not l.strip():
                subFile.write(
                    eventInfo + "\n"
                )  # Add event to the subfile
                eventInfo = ""  # Reinit event info
                eventCounter += 1
                if eventCounter == 700:
                    subFile.close()
                    fileId += 1
                    subFile = open(
                        os.path.join(
                            catdir,
                            "Paquete_Continental_"
                            + str(fileId)
                            + ".out",
                        ),
                        "w+",
                    )
                    eventCounter = 0
            else:
                eventInfo += l
subFile.close()
```

Expected results: Event info of earthquakes with 'RSN N' (where N≠3)
Actual results: First line of events with 'RSN  3' is deleted but not the remaining event info.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise against checking if the string is at an exact location (e.g. `l[45:51]`) since a single character can mess that up, you can instead check if the entire string contains "RSN  3" with `if "RSN  3" in l`

With the `line = l[:-1]` you only get the last character of the line, so the `line[1:15]` won't work since it's not an array.

But if you need to delete several lines, you could just check if the current line **contains** "RSN  3", and then read line after line until one contains "RSN  " while skipping the ones in between.

```py
skip = False
for line in fileContent:
    if "RSN  3" in line:
        skip = True
        continue
    if "RSN  " in line and "RSN  3" not in line:
        skip = False
        # rest of the logic
    if skip:
        continue
```

This way you don't even parse the blocks whose first line contains "RSN  3".

Comment: Hi, I didn't have time to check your answer. It seems as a smart approach, just one question...by rest of the logic do you mean to append and write the file?

Comment: And when you say-> "RSN  " in line and "RSN  3" not in line, is it skiping events with (e.g.) "RSN  8"?

Comment: Yes, you could add those lines to a different array and then process just them afterwards, that way this whole loop is just a filter.

Think about it, does a line that contains _RSN 8_ match both of those conditions? Does it contain _RSN_, but doesn't contain _RSN 3_? :)

Comment: Makes sense, I actually found one way editing your answer. Still thanks a lot!